# Firestore Rules - request.query.limit denies list collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have in my Firestore Database a called `reports`.

In my Angular app, I allow to fetch only 10 results at a single query:

```
angularFirestore.collection('reports', ref => ref.limit(10));
```

As expected, the app shows up to 10 results.

To make sure Firestore won't allow any bigger limitation, I wrote the following rule:

```
match /reports/{reportId} {
  allow list: if request.query.limit && request.query.limit <= 10
}
```

For some reason, the app has failed to get the data from Firestore due to "Missing or insufficient permissions".

To make sure that the problem lies on this statement, I changed the following rule to:

```
match /reports/{reportId} {
  allow list;
}
```

And it worked.

Then I tried to write this rule in "baby steps", so I wrote:

```
match /reports/{reportId} {
  allow list: if request.query.limit;
}
```

And surprisingly it failed. Now, my question is why does `request.query.limit` is a falsey value while I explicitly wrote `.limit(10)` in my app? after all, when I write `allow list;` I get 10 documents and not beyond.

**Edit:**

It looks like even when I write the following rule, it fails:

```
match /reports/{reportId} {
  allow list: request.query;
}
```

Comment: As soon as you started saying anything other than "read", "list", "write", "update", "delete" after "allow", you were making a rule that would never be true.

Comment: @DougStevenson It was written here like so by mistake. I have updated my question. Anyway, I've already found an answer (look below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query) mislead me by given the example:

```
// Limit documents per request to 50
allow list: if request.query.limit && request.query.limit <= 50
```

While there should be only :

```
allow list: if request.query.limit <= 50
```

Comment: Does it limit the documents from read?? I want a solution for limiting documents read in firestore for every user